# Installation: file not found but it exists

Tags: software-installation, configuration

During installation

```
john@john-PC:/bin/musashi-core-1.0.4$ ./configure
```

I've got the error message

```
./configure: line 19741: .: mssEnc.sh: file not found
```

The corresponding line in **configure** is

```
. mssEnc.sh
```

while **mssEnc.sh** is in the corresponding folder

```
john@john-PC:/bin/musashi-core-1.0.4$ dir
aclocal.m4    config.h.in   COPYING  INSTALL     ltmain.sh  mssEnc.sh
AUTHORS       config.log    depcomp  install-sh  Makefile.am    NEWS
ChangeLog     config.sub    dm       lib     Makefile.in    README
cmd       configure     exp      libtool     missing    setdocenc.sh
config.guess  configure.in  help     ltconfig    mkinstalldirs  upddocenc.sh
```

What's wrong with my installation?

ADDED

Thanks to @L. D. James's instructions I could configure the package but then I failed to compile it.

```
john@john-PC:~/Musashi/musashi-core-1.0.4$ make
```

which yields

```
fatal error: zlib.h: No such     file     or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: try to change from: `. mssEnc.sh` to `bash mssEnc.sh`

Comment: @Benny That would change the intent of the `configure` line.  The intent is to source the `mmsEnc.sh` file, not execute it.  He could use `source` instead of bash.  However, that wouldn't change from what is already there the `.`..

Comment: Try using a full pathname to the mssEnc.sh file (ie. `/bin/musashi-core-1.0.4/mssEnc.sh`.

Comment: Where is your source directory located.  From your `dir` command output, it appears that you are looking at the file in `/bin/musashi-core-1.0.4` directory.  You shouldn't compile programs in the `/bin` directory.  Your account by default won't have access to work in that directory.  Try to compile programs in the `/bin` directory can very easily introduce many problems that you haven't noticed yet.  You should create a folder in your own space and configure and compile it from there.

Comment: You would have to install the development package it's trying to use.  The `zlib.h` is included in the `libghc-zlib-dev` package.  You can install the package with: `sudo apt install libghc-zlib-dev`.

Comment: @L. D. James Thanks a lot. It helped.  Now I have 
    fatal error: libxml/parserInternals.h: No such file or directory
What should I install now?

Comment: libxml++2.6-dev

Comment: @L. D. James Thanks a lot. How I could find this package on my own? There are some error messages but there is no more fatal errors. How can I be sure that the compiling was successful?

Comment: Which package are you trying to find.  Most errors are fatal.  It's the warnings that can be ignored.  I located the missing developer libraries by looking at the output in the text in your question.  I used `apt-cache search zlib` for the last one that I gave you.

Comment: @L. D. James Thanks again
I meant how could I find a package for libxml/parserInternals.h?

How should I deal with errors like that?

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:624: recipe for target 'csv2xt' failed
make[2]: *** [csv2xt] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Musashi/musashi-core-1.0.4/cmd'
Makefile:242: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/john/Musashi/musashi-core-1.0.4'
Makefile:171: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46923/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-8k14).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **What is Wrong with your Installation**.

The program isn't installed.  You are at the `configure` point of the compiling.  The package will have to be `configured` before it can be `compiled` and `installed`.

You will have to create a folder in your personal space to run the `./configure` part of the process.

- **Do Not** copy any files to the `/bin` folder.  That is't a part of the install process.
- **Do Not** Run any part of the process as `sudo` until the package is fully configured and compiled.

You would have to first complete the `./configure` process successful.  Then run the compile part of the process with `make`.  If this succeeds without fatal errors you can then and only then install the program.

The command to install is:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Some packages may have special instructions for the compiling and installation.  For that you would have to refer to the `README` contents of the package.

You should not run any of the steps using `sudo` until the programs is fully compiled.

The best thing you can do is remove what you have copied to the `/bin` folder (the musashi-core-1.0.4$).  Then start the compiling fresh with a fresh copy of the source.  Then follow the steps provided in the **README** text file which in most cases are these steps:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.  I created a new folder     ~/Musashi/     and tried to configure there with the same outcome...

Comment: Did you read the `README` text file and follow any special preliminaries provided by the author?  If you would provide a link to where the package was downloaded I'll study it directly.

Comment: @ L.D.James Thanks. I followed author's instructions from http://musashien.sourceforge.net/install.shtml

Comment: You would have to give a full pathname to the `mssEnc.sh` file to correct this in the `configure` routine.  This is an error in the part of the package.  Type this to get the full pathname of the `mssEnc.sh` file: `pwd`.  You will then get something similar to `/home/user/musashi-core-1.0.4`.  add that to the line so that the pathname will be: `musashi-core-1.0.4/mssEnc.sh`.  The line would then be: `. musashi-core-1.0.4/mssEnc.sh`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But now I have a compiling problem. I put it in my original question, would you be so kind to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is that `mssEnc.sh` has encoding problem.
Converted the script's encoding by [dos2unix](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dos2unix.1.html).

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix -y
dos2unix mssEnc.sh
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not help...

Comment: Changing the content of the `mssEnc.sh` file isn't going to make ti become found.

Comment: Should I recover the original encoding?

Comment: if it's not solved is mean that the file is already unix and not dos, so nothing has been changed